# moment().fromNow() depends on user's PC time

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have an issue with fromNow function in moment js working with user timezones.

It works correctly only when clocks on the user's PC set absolutely correctly.

For example, If I set my clock to -15 minutes from the real time and post a new comment on a website it will show "comment posted in 15 minutes" instead of "comment posted a few seconds ago".

I tried

```
moment(dateInUTCFromServer).local().fromNow() // in 15 minutes.
```

and

```
moment.utc(dateInUTCFromServer).fromNow() // in 15 minutes.
```

They do now work correctly.
`dateInUTCFromServer` is a regular timestamp date object from a database. I want to show this date for users in "from now" format. `console.log(dateInUTCFromServer) // 2020-01-29 12:25:48`

It many cases it gives me *"in a second"* instead of *"a few seconds ago"* even when I try to set the correct time on my PC.
In some cases, such issues may be critical. For example, showing deadlines.

Is it possible to use "from now" format ignoring user's PC time settings?

Comment: What specifically is `nowFromServer`.  Is it a string? a number? a `Date` object? something else?  Please also show an example value you are actually using.  Thanks.

Comment: BTW, you cannot guarantee the user's clock accuracy, but time zone should generally not factor into such comparisons.

Comment: Dear @MattJohnson-Pint, I have just updated my question. nowFromServer (changed to dateInUTCFromServer) is a timestamp date object from the database in UTC format (2020-01-29 12:25:48). I want to show this data as "... minutes ago" to users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you said your dates are in UTC, and in ISO format but do not include a `Z` or other offset indicator, then the correct code is your second example:

```
moment.utc(dateInUTCFromServer).fromNow()
```

The clock on an end user's PC is not something you can control, but it's generally acceptable for one to assume that the end user is synchronizing time. Especially in applications that use third-party authentication (such as a Google or Facebook login) and/or use SSL certificates - both require accurate timestamp validation.

If however you find it critical for the time on the client to be ignored, then you'll need to pass the server's current time to your application.

```
moment.utc(dateInUTCFromServer).from(currentTimeInUTCFromServer)
```

Alternatively, if your back end is Node.js, you could just run the original code on the server and pass the string result down to the client.